# PHP script throwing 500 internal error

Tags: php, ajax

I have a Javascript script that sends an Ajax request via POST to the following PHP script. $db is passed from up above, but I know that part works. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error from this. I am unable to see the server logs, so I can't get more detailed information than this. Anyone know what I can do to fix it?

```
function register($db) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0] == $user) {
        echo "taken";
    }
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')";

        if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability.  Are you using a recent PHP version, e.g. 5.4+? Your `mysqli_fetch_array()[0]` is illegal syntax in earlier PHPs.

Comment: Do any other PHP scripts work on this server?

Comment: Please check the file permision & .htaccess file in your server

Comment: Check if your PHP version supports `()[]` -> getting an element from an array function.

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers:  Uh, that's NOT what I said. You're now mixing mysql and mysqli libraries. I'd -1 you if I could...

Comment: This script doesn't have to be secure at all--so no worries about SQL injection. I just didn't take the time to learn prepared statements yet. I'll check the version, as I'm not quite sure off the top of my head--it's on my school server.

Comment: It's never too early to learn good practice. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a parse error which is fixed in later versions of PHP. The following line of code is not valid <= PHP 5.4:

```
if (mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0] == $user) {
```

In order to fix this, you need to change that line to the following:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row[0] == $user) {
```

Also, your code also has a pretty severe SQL injection vulnerability. You need to sanitise your variables before using them in queries. For integers and floats, I recommend you do the following:

```
$myInt   = (isset($_POST['myInt'])   ?   (int)$_POST['myInt']   : null);
$myFloat = (isset($_POST['myFloat']) ? (float)$_POST['myFloat'] : null);
```

For strings, you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as follows:

```
$myStr = (isset($_POST['myStr']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['myStr']) : null);
```

In your case, your `$user` and `$pass` variables need to be sanitised as the string is above. The reason for forcing the types of numbers you're receiving via `$_POST` is that it entirely negates any possibility of someone passing through a value which is not valid. Anything which is not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc that is cast as (int) will become 0.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had been scratching my head for several hours about this stupid issue. While this script doesn't need to be secure by any means whatsoever, I do need to learn prepared statements and whatnot. I'll implement your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: @David's answer above is how you should do it using the `mysqli()` class properly with prepared statements and bound parameters, however mixing styles mid-project can lead to pain. If your code already uses the function aliases (eg, `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, etc) you're probably better off sticking with that style until such a time that you can replace all the database code with the newer style.

Comment: Also also, you probably want to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `_array` as it will allow you to use `$row['user']` instead of `$row[0]` to get the value, which is much more readable.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into that asap. I've got about 1000 lines of code so far between various languages, but it won't be too much of a pain. I need to learn prepared statements and sanitize my inputs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a corollary than an actual answer, but it is far too long for the format of a comment.

For the sake of a followup to @MarcB's comment, you should change your code to be invulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$link)
{
    die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
}

$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
$stmt->bind_result($testUsername);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "taken";
}
else
{
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "success";
}
```